# Trying to change div background color with sliders

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, background-color

I am trying to change this div using the sliders embedded in the div.

```
<div data-role="content" class = "main" id = "main">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="slider" class="redSlider">      
        <label for="red" color="red">
            Red
        </label>
        <input id="red" type="range" name="redSlider" value="255" min="0" max="255"
        data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" onchange = "changeBackground()">
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="slider" class="greenSlider">
        <label for="green">
            Green
        </label>
        <input id="green" type="range" name="greenSlider" value="255" min="0"
        max="255" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" onchange = "changeBackground()">
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="slider" class="blueSlider">
        <label for="blue">
            Blue
        </label>
        <input id="blue" type="range" name="blueSlider" value="255" min="0" max="255"
        data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" onchange = "changeBackground()">
    </div>

</div>
```

My function is below. I am new to javascript, but I believe my error is in the function itself.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function changeBackground () {
        var r = parseInt(document.getElementById('redSlider').value);
            g = parseInt(document.getElementById('greenSlider').value);
            b = parseInt(document.getElementById('blueSlider').value);

        var rHex = (r < 16) ? "0" + r.toString(16) : r.toString(16);
            gHex = (g < 16) ? "0" + g.toString(16) : g.toString(16);
            bHex = (b < 16) ? "0" + b.toString(16) : b.toString(16);

        var hexCode = '#' + rHex + gHex + bHex;

    document.getElementById('main').background-color= hexCode;
}   
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Did you use the console in your browser to debug your JavaScript? Also, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: use `backgroundColor` not `background-color`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres quite a lot wrong with the code.

`background-color` is invalid for JS. You should be using `backgroundColor`

You are referencing elements with id of `redSlider` when the element id is `red`. `redSlider` is the name of the element.

`toString` doesn't take any parameters.
What you are looking to build is an `rgb` spectrum not a hex code. Hex codes contain letters when the value is greater than 9. You would need more calculations to generate a hex value this way.

I have created a fiddle with the working code for you. http://jsfiddle.net/4o7aes29/